# Renew IP caused some problems

Tags: networking, router, ipconfig

I have Win 8.1 and try to renew my IP address, but when I typed in CMD "ipconfig/release" suddenly I got 14 Local Area Connections. Before I had just one. Also the moment I typed that and hit enter, I lost internet access. I must physically restart my cable modem. After that I try to renew address but got message "no operation can be performed on local area connection 14 while it has its media disconnected" I didn't disconnect anything and also how I got all 14 Local Area Connections?
Thx!

Answer (score 0):

When you entered ipconfig /release you released the DHCP settings on your network connection.

I can't but speculate on the 14 Local Area Connections, but some software, like VirtualBox and Hamachi make pseudo LAC's to function.

Without any information on how your connection is configured (are you using automatic DHCP or a Static IP?), I'm afraid I can't answer your question.

I'm not actually sure what your question is, besides where the 14 LACs came from.

Comment: My question is: is this normal state and how can I revert it back to one LAC, because right now I don't know which one is in use and what are all those LACs doing? Maybe this is a noob question, but I'm not familiar with networking. Thank you!